# Android Emulator does not start at hardware acceleration, linux/ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, emulation, intel

i recently reninstalled ubuntu, now i have 17.04 version and android emulator with hardware graphic performance doesnt start.

after starting there is a loading with "starting avd..." but nothing happens.

when i switch graphic performance to software emulator run succesfully but is really slow. before reinstall everything was fine.

things i have tried:

- i have virtualization in bios enabled
- i have kvm installed, my cpu support it (kvm-ok)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation all done
- `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils`
- `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386`
- some others perhaps but after all this things i cant remember

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are not using ARM image for the emulator. X86 image should work fine and will also take the benefit of hardware acceleration. For an emulator with x86 image and android marshmallow, follow following procedure (Everything from terminal, tested on mac):

1. Download the system image for emulator by using sdkmanager from terminal. sdkmanager should be present at /sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager, make sure this bin folder is in path.

> sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"

2. Emulator can be created by using avdmanager. avdmanager should be present at sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager. We are using x86_32 android-23 image. You might need to update sdk using "sdkmanager --update" to get avdmanager. Here -n defines the name of the emulator, -b defines the abi to be used and -g is the tag to be used for avd. We don't need the custom hardware while creating emulator.

> avdmanager create avd -n "x86_32_23" -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" -b "google_apis/x86" -g "google_apis"

3. Now emulator can be launched

> emulator -avd x86_32_23

Comment: damn, it worked. but why? i mean, its still software acceleration but its a lot faster than that created by window version of avdmanager

Comment: Great that it worked, I think from the window you might be choosing some different configuration for the emulator.
Point to remember is:
1. The performance of Arm machine sucks on most of the machine.
2. It always better to use google image rather than default

Answer (score 8):

Go to emulator/lib64 and remove libstdc++ directory

Comment: There is no directory called `libstdc++` in `emulator/lib64`

Comment: You are right, after some update they decided to don't ship it anymore with emulator, so basically they removed this dir by themself. Good decision.